# How to modify the backgroup color of label in the multiple-ggproto using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggproto

I want to draw a graph which is familiar to the [enterotype plot](http://enterotype.embl.de/images/pcoa.png) in the [research](http://enterotype.embl.de/enterotypes.html). But my new multiple-ggproto seems terrible as showed in `p1`, owing to the missing backgroup color of the label. I've tried multiple variations of this, for example modify `GeomLabel$draw_panel` in order to reset the default arguments of geom in `ggplot2::ggproto`. However, I could not find the `labelGrob()` function which is removed in `ggplot2` and `grid` package. Thus, the solution of modification didn't work. How to modify the backgroup color of label in the multiple-ggproto. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Here is my code and two pictures.
`p1`: the background color of label should be white or the text color should be black.
[image]
`P2`:displays the wrong point color, line color and legend. [image]

```
geom_enterotype <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",  position = "identity", 
                            alpha = 0.3, prop = 0.5, ..., lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", 
                            linemitre = 1, arrow = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, parse = FALSE, 
                            nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, label.padding = unit(0.15, "lines"), 
                            label.r = unit(0.15, "lines"), label.size = 0.1, 
                            show.legend = TRUE, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
library(ggplot2)
# create new stat and geom for PCA scatterplot with ellipses
StatEllipse <- ggproto("StatEllipse", Stat, 
    required_aes = c("x", "y"), 
    compute_group = function(., data, scales, level = 0.75, segments = 51, ...) {
    library(MASS)
    dfn <- 2
    dfd <- length(data$x) - 1
    if (dfd < 3) {
        ellipse <- rbind(c(NA, NA))
    } else {
        v <- cov.trob(cbind(data$x, data$y))
        shape <- v$cov
        center <- v$center
        radius <- sqrt(dfn * qf(level, dfn, dfd))
        angles <- (0:segments) * 2 * pi/segments
        unit.circle <- cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles))
        ellipse <- t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol(shape)))
    }
    ellipse <- as.data.frame(ellipse)
    colnames(ellipse) <- c("x", "y")
    return(ellipse)
})

# write new ggproto 
GeomEllipse <- ggproto("GeomEllipse", Geom, 
    draw_group = function(data, panel_scales, coord) {
            n <- nrow(data)
            if (n == 1) 
            return(zeroGrob())
            munched <- coord_munch(coord, data, panel_scales)
            munched <- munched[order(munched$group), ]
            first_idx <- !duplicated(munched$group)
            first_rows <- munched[first_idx, ]
            grid::pathGrob(munched$x, munched$y, default.units = "native", 
                           id = munched$group, 
                           gp = grid::gpar(col = first_rows$colour, 
                           fill = alpha(first_rows$fill, first_rows$alpha), lwd = first_rows$size * .pt, lty = first_rows$linetype))
             }, 
             default_aes = aes(colour = "NA", fill = "grey20", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA, prop = 0.5), 
             handle_na = function(data, params) {
                   data
           }, 
          required_aes = c("x", "y"), 
          draw_key = draw_key_path
)

# create a new stat for PCA scatterplot with lines which totally directs to the center
StatConline <- ggproto("StatConline", Stat, 
    compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    library(miscTools)
    library(MASS)
    df <- data.frame(data$x,data$y)
    mat <- as.matrix(df)
    center <- cov.trob(df)$center
    names(center)<- NULL 
    mat_insert <- insertRow(mat, 2, center )
    for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    mat_insert <- insertRow( mat_insert, 2*i, center )
    next
    }
    mat_insert <- mat_insert[-c(2:3),]
    rownames(mat_insert) <- NULL
    mat_insert <- as.data.frame(mat_insert,center)
    colnames(mat_insert) =c("x","y")
    return(mat_insert)
    },
    required_aes = c("x", "y")

)

# create a new stat for PCA scatterplot with center labels
StatLabel <- ggproto("StatLabel" ,Stat,
               compute_group = function(data, scales) {
                library(MASS)
                df <- data.frame(data$x,data$y)
                center <- cov.trob(df)$center
                names(center)<- NULL 
                center <- t(as.data.frame(center))
                center <- as.data.frame(cbind(center))
                colnames(center) <- c("x","y")
                rownames(center) <- NULL
                return(center)
                },
                required_aes = c("x", "y")
)


layer1 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
layer2 <- layer(stat = StatEllipse, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = GeomEllipse, position = position, show.legend = FALSE, 
                     inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(na.rm = na.rm, prop = prop, alpha = alpha, ...))
layer3 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat =  StatConline, geom = GeomPath, 
                                   position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
                                   params = list(lineend = lineend, linejoin = linejoin, 
                                   linemitre = linemitre, arrow = arrow, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      stop("Specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`", 
           call. = FALSE)
    }
    position <- position_nudge(nudge_x, nudge_y)
  }
layer4 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatLabel, geom = GeomLabel, 
        position = position, show.legend = FALSE, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(parse = parse, label.padding = label.padding, 
                      label.r = label.r, label.size = label.size, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
return(list(layer1,layer2,layer3,layer4))
}

# data
data(Cars93, package = "MASS")
car_df <- Cars93[, c(3, 5, 13:15, 17, 19:25)]
car_df <- subset(car_df, Type == "Large" | Type == "Midsize" | Type == "Small")
x1 <- mean(car_df$Price) + 2 * sd(car_df$Price)
x2 <- mean(car_df$Price) - 2 * sd(car_df$Price)
car_df <- subset(car_df, Price > x2 | Price < x1)
car_df <- na.omit(car_df)

# Principal Component Analysis
car.pca <- prcomp(car_df[, -1], scale = T)
car.pca_pre <- cbind(as.data.frame(predict(car.pca)[, 1:2]), car_df[, 1])
colnames(car.pca_pre) <- c("PC1", "PC2", "Type")
xlab <- paste("PC1(", round(((car.pca$sdev[1])^2/sum((car.pca$sdev)^2)), 2) * 100, "%)", sep = "")
ylab <- paste("PC2(", round(((car.pca$sdev[2])^2/sum((car.pca$sdev)^2)), 2) * 100, "%)", sep = "")
head(car.pca_pre)

#plot
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(car.pca_pre, aes(PC1, PC2, fill = Type , color= Type ,label = Type)) + 
geom_enterotype()
p2 <- ggplot(car.pca_pre, aes(PC1, PC2, fill = Type , label = Type)) + 
geom_enterotype()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually change the colour scale to give it more emphasis against the background fill colour:

```
p3 <- ggplot(car.pca_pre, aes(PC1, PC2, fill = Type , color = Type, label = Type)) + 
  geom_enterotype() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red4", "green4", "blue4"))
p3
```

[image]
You can additionally adjust your fill colours by changing the alpha values, or assigning different colour values to give better contrast to your labels.

```
p4 <- ggplot(car.pca_pre, aes(PC1, PC2, label = Type, shape = Type, fill = Type, colour = Type)) + 
  geom_enterotype() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("pink", "lightgreen", "skyblue"), 1)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red4", "green4", "blue4"))
p4
```

[image]

Finally, if you want a background white colour to your labels, you have to remove the fill option. You can also additionally assign a shape value.

As you can observe, the background text colour is associated with the shape fill colour, while the text label colour is associated with the line colour, the  the shape border colour.

```
 p5 <- ggplot(car.pca_pre, aes(PC1, PC2, label = Type, shape = Type, colour = Type)) + 
  geom_enterotype() + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red4", "green4", "blue4"))
 p5
```

[image]